# How to add political boundaries and coastlines within the seaborn facets?

Tags: python, seaborn

The following code produces faceted plots of output from my climate model (WRF), however without any political boundaries or coastlines.
I tried adding these with the `ax` argument, `(ax.add_feature(states), ax.coastlines('50m'))`. However just discovered that facets do not accept `ax` arguments. I want to add coastlines and political boundaries to the subplots. Any ideas how to do it?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import netCDF4
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import xarray as xr

ds = xr.open_mfdataset("C:path\*.nc",concat_dim='Time', combine='nested', compat='no_conflicts', preprocess=None, engine=None, data_vars='all', coords='all', parallel=False, join='outer', attrs_file=None,)

C = ds.SNOWH

C.plot(row='Time', col_wrap=5)
```

[image: Here are example of the plots I get:]

Comment: This is not reproducible code ([mcve]), please add the missing import for xr (xarray?), and whichever (public-domain) shapefile you used to get the political boundaries or coastlines. We should be able to run your code.